# Disable HTML button after clicking to prevent double-click

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit, double-submit-prevention

I want to prevent double-clicks, so setting the `disabled` attribute on the `input` element upon a click event seems like the right thing to do. And other stackoverflow answers reflect that. So this is what I wrote in CoffeeScript with jQuery:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', ->
  $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  $(this).val('Sending')
)
```

I have `addClass('disabled')` for Foundation.

Generally this works. However, if I click back, the button is still disabled. If I go to the page and the page was cached, the button is still disabled. Is there a JavaScript library that deals with all these little issues? Seems like this is a very common need. Is there just a little bit more JavaScript/jQuery I need to add to the above?

I would've thought HTML5 would have some mechanism for this by now.

***UPDATE***: I tried to listen for `pageshow` events and un-disable submit buttons:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('pageshow', function() {
  console.log('pageshowed')
  $(this).removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled').val('Submit');
});
```

Nothing happens though, not even when the page is first loaded. Am I using `pageshow` wrong?

Comment: Maybe, you can use quick and dirty workaround: enable buttons on document.ready?

Comment: @IvanKolmycheck - that doesn't work. `$(document).ready` doesn't re-execute its handler when the page is cached or going back in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the explainig, that was just wild guess.

Comment: Then try [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching#pageshow_event)

Comment: @robertc - I'll try that, but looks like pageshow only works for Firefox?

Comment: Works in Chrome as well as Firefox, not sure about Safari or IE (not on Windows), doesn't work on Opera (but will work in Opera 15, since same engine as Chrome), try `typeof window.onpageshow` in console

Comment: @robertc - I updated the question, I could not listen to the pageshow event at all, neither Firefox nor Chrome worked.

Comment: `pageshow` is an event on the window, not on an `input` element.

Comment: @robertc - that worked, I didn't have time to update the question before. Put that as an answer and I'll give you credit for it. I also had to make the button click actually a form submit event, otherwise chrome would not submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`pageshow` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching#pageshow_event) on the `window` object.  Works in Chrome and Safari as well as Firefox, not sure about IE, doesn't work on Opera 12 (but will work in Opera 15, since same engine as Chrome).  Try `typeof window.onpageshow` in console to detect.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.auto-submit-disable')
    .submit(function () {
      $(this).find('button,input[type=submit]')
        .attr('disabled', 'true');
    });
});

if ($('.auto-submit-disable'))
  window.onunload = function(){}; // This forces re-execution of js
```

After that, just put `class="auto-submit-disable"` on your forms. Notice that the method is heavy to browsers, because repeating all JS upon back-navigation is heavy.

So it's not recommended as a general method to run on all your pages!!

Comment: Can't you can still submit a form without a button? Like, via pressing enter?

Comment: No, most browsers do not accept <enter> when there's no active submit input.